# How to ensure that the vector in homogeneous coordinates is still a vector after transformation

Tags: c++, matrix, graphics

I performed an `MVP transformation` on the vertices of the model. In theory, I must apply the inverse transpose matrix of the MVP transformation to ***the normal***.

This is the derivation process：

`(A, B, C)` is the normal of the plane where the point `(x, y, z)` lies
[image]

For a vector, such as `(x0, y0, z0)`, it is `(x0, y0, z0, 0)` in homogeneous coordinates. After transformation, it should still be a vector, like `(x1, y1, z1, 0)`, This requires that the last row of the 4 * 4 transformation matrix is all 0 except for the elements in the last column, otherwise it will become `(x1, y1, z1, n)` after the transformation.

In fact, my MVP transformation matrix cannot satisfy this point after undergoing inverse transpose transformation.

Code:

```
Mat<4, 4> View(const Vec3& pos){
    Mat<4, 4> pan{1, 0, 0, -pos.x,
                0, 1, 0, -pos.y,
                0, 0, 1, -pos.z,
                0, 0, 0, 1};
    Vec3 v = Cross(camera.lookAt, camera.upDirection).Normalize();
    Mat<4, 4> rotate{v.x, v.y, v.z, 0,
                     camera.upDirection.x, camera.upDirection.y, camera.upDirection.z, 0,
                     -camera.lookAt.x, -camera.lookAt.y, -camera.lookAt.z, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 1};
    return rotate * pan;
}

Mat<4, 4> Projection(double near, double far, double fov, double aspectRatio){
    double angle = fov * PI / 180;

    double t = -near * tan(angle / 2);
    double b = -t;
    double r = t * aspectRatio;
    double l = -r;

    Mat<4, 4> zoom{2 / (r - l), 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 2 / (t - b), 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 2 / (near - far), 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1};
    Mat<4, 4> pan{1, 0, 0, -(l + r) / 2,
                    0, 1, 0, -(t + b) / 2,
                    0, 0, 1, -(near + far) / 2,
                    0, 0, 0, 1};
    Mat<4, 4> extrusion{near, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, near, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, near + far, -near * far,
                        0, 0, 1, 0};

    Mat<4, 4> ret = zoom * pan * extrusion;
    return ret;
}
Mat<4, 4> modelMatrix = Mat<4, 4>::identity();
Mat<4, 4> viewMatrix = View(camera.position);
Mat<4, 4> projectionMatrix = Projection(-0.1, -50, camera.fov, camera.aspectRatio);
Mat<4, 4> mvp = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
Mat<4, 4> mvpInverseTranspose = mvp.Inverse().Transpose();
```

mvp:

```
-2.29032  0        0.763441   -2.68032e-16 
0         -2.41421 0          0 
-0.317495 0        -0.952486  2.97455 
0.316228  0        0.948683   -3.16228
```

mvpInverseTranspose:

```
-0.392957   0          0.130986   0 
0           -0.414214  0          0 
-4.99       0          -14.97     -4.99 
-4.69377    0          -14.0813   -5.01
```

Comment: Can you clarify the reason why you transpose the inverted matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to understand the problem. The lighting should be calculated in world space, so I only need to apply the inverse transpose matrix of `the model transformation` to the ***normal***.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, it should be sufficient to use the inverse-transposed of the model-view matrix instead of the model-view-projection matrix to transform the normal vectors to view-space and not into clip-space.

It is okay, that the w-component is not bound to be zero after transforming with the inverse transpose.

**Reason:**
Already the inverse-transpose of 4x4 affine matrix (the type of the model-view matrix) maps a normal vector of the form [x, y, z, 0] to the vector  [x', y', z', w'] with w' != 0 in general.

Here is why:
Consider the inverse of the affine matrix

```
/ R t \^-1 = /R^-1 -R^-1*t\
\ 0 1 /      \0    1      /
```

with 0 being the 1x3 zero vector, t the 3x1 translation vector, R the 3x3 linear part, and ^-1 the inverse.

So its inverse-transpose is

```
/ R t \^-T = / (R^-1)^T         0^T \
\ 0 1 /      \ (-R^-1 * t)^T     1  /
```

Now multiply the inverse-transpose with [x,y,z,0]^T you will get w'= (-R^-1 * t)^T * [x, y, z]^T + 0*1 != 0

**So what can you do about it?**

**Option 1: For normals ignore the w' part.**

The recipe for transforming normal vectors with affine matrices is to take its inverse transpose and then ignore the w' part of the result.

That means, simply use [x', y', z']. You can even do the division (if w' != 0), i.e., 1/w' * [x', y', z'] because normalize(1/w*[x', y', z']) = normalize([x', y', z']). Remember with normal vectors, you are interested in their directions, not their lengths.

**Option 2: Use the 3x3 sub-matrix**

Translating a direction makes no sense. Remember your maths teachers drawing arrows on the board at different locations and stating that the underlying vectors are identical. For normal vectors, it is sufficient to use the upper-left 3x3 sub-matrix of the affine matrix.

However, you still need inverse-transpose it.

**Normal Vectors into Clip-Space**
I kept saying affine matrices because transforming normal vectors with projective matrices like the MVP is something I would not recommend.

Normals are typically used for lighting. That happens in model, view, tangent, world, or light space. However, the model-view-projection (MVP) matrix here contains a projective part in form of the projection matrix P. The projection matrix maps to clip-space. That is not the space where lighting is carried out, but clipping, culling, and preparing the coordinates for the perspective z divide.

I guess, if you do the maths carefully, you should be able to do it, but never considered even thinking about it.

It is a lot easier to do lighting in any space prior to clip-space.